# Which EcmaScript 6 features can be translate to ES5 code?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Classes, modules, arrow functions etc;all of this is more or less just syntactic sugar added to JavaScript. In ES5 we could achieve the same using design patterns.

My question targets safety of writing ES6 code which is then translated to ES5 code for compatibility reasons.

Which ES6 features should I avoid when ES5 compatibility is required?

Comment: All of these can be transpiled https://babeljs.io/docs/advanced/transformers/

Comment: Are you using a transpiler?  If so, then you will need to consult the specific transpiler to see exactly which ES6 features it supports and which it doesn't.

Comment: Babel says that it does not support proxies, subclassing of some built-ins, only some tail recursion.  Many features require the installation of a polyfill in addition to the transpiling.

Comment: Hey, you always can write an ES6 engine in ES5, so certainly everything can be "translated" :-) You rather should consult the documentation of the specific transpiler you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most new language features can be transpiled (as transpilers like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) and [TypeScript](http://typescriptlang.org/) prove). Additions to the standard library can generally be polyfilled.

What you can't transpile, however, are features like **tail call optimization** because they would require modifications to the JavaScript engine itself.

Also, you **can't subclass built-in constructors** like `Array` or `Error`. Finally, **proxies** can neither be 100% transpiled nor polyfilled. Pretty much all other ES6 features, though, can be lowered to ES5 (including generators, which can be turned into state machines).

Check out the [ES6 compatibility table](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/) for an exhaustive overview of all features that are supported by various transpilers.

Comment: `Proxy` cannot be polyfilled either.

Comment: @FelixKling Right. I've now highlighted *proxies* in bold to stress that point.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't notice you mentioned it.

Comment: Babel does handle TCO for self-recursive cases, but not for the general case.